# Javascript Logic

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I just modified an older code and now nothing seems to be working. Could you please guide where am I going wrong.

Some of the things that aren't working are:

Earlier, focus would always stay on the only input field present on the screen. (Now it doesnt), also the if else conditions in the code arent working. On keyup function isnt working either.

```
<script language="javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#serialNumber").focus();
        $("#scroll-pane").jScrollPane();
        $(document).keydown(function() {
            $("#serialNumber").focus();
        });
        var code = $("#hiddenSerialCode").val();

        $("#serialNumber").keyup(function() {
            var $this = $(this);
            var d = $(this).val();
            var d5 = d.substring(0, 5);

            if (d.length != 20) {
                alert('Incorrect Serial Code');
            }
            else if (d.length == 20 && d5 != code) {
                var serialCode = d.substring(0, 8);
                alert('Serial Code: ' + serialCode);
                $(this).val("");
            }
            else if (d.length == 20 && d5 == code) {
                var flagNumber = d.substring(0, 6);
                var errorNumber = d.substring(7, 10);
                alert('Flag Number ' + flagNumber + '\nError Number ' + errorNumber);
                $(this).val("");
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

HTML Code: --------------

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>
    <input type="text" id="serialNumber" class="" />
    <input type="hidden" id="hiddenSerialCode" value="01327"/>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>

<div id="scroll-pane" class="scroll-pane">
```

Old working Code: ------

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#serialCode").focus();
    $(document).keydown(function() {
        $("#serialCode").focus();
    });

    $("#serialCode").keyup(function(){
        var $this = $(this);
        var d = $(this).val();
        if (d.length >= 5){
            //$this.attr("disabled","disabled")
            var $code = d.substring(0,8) ;
            alert('code is ' + $code);

        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Did you compare against your older code? Can you post your older code? You do use source control, right?

Comment: Note that the `language` attribute for the `<script>` tag is [deprecated](http://www.doheth.co.uk/codelair/html-css/deprecated#lang). You should use `<script type="text/javascript">` instead.

Comment: need to include your HTML that is output to the browser so we can see what is happening

Comment: @Oded, I posted the older code as well, I made changes in the older code, but even now with older code, focus and alert is working fine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main problem with your code is that `$("#scroll-pane").jScrollPane();` refers to an undefined method.

If you take that line out your code functions.

So, you have to make sure to include the **[`jScrollPane()` plugin](http://jscrollpane.kelvinluck.com/)** somewhere in your code.

If you just want to scroll to `#scroll-pane` use **[`.animate()`](http://api.jquery.com/animate/)**:

```
$('html,body').animate({
    scrollTop: $('#scroll-pane').offset().top},
    'slow');
```

Additionally, your `if` statement should probably be `if (d.length > 20)` otherwise you get an error on every single keypress. You could do a check with **[`.blur()`](http://api.jquery.com/blur/)** for `if (d.length != 20)`.

Also, you might want to check for a valid serial number before `d.length` of 20, since it looks like a serial number only has a length of 9.

Finally, as a note, you define `$this` as `$(this)`, but then you use `$(this)`. For values you could simply use `this.value`.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#serialNumber").focus();
    // $("#scroll-pane").jScrollPane(); - Include plugin if you want to use this.
    $(document).keydown(function() {
        $("#serialNumber").focus();
    });
    var code = $("#hiddenSerialCode").val();

    $("#serialNumber").keyup(function() {
        var $this = $(this);
        var d = $this.val();
        var d5 = d.substring(0, 5);

        if (d.length > 20) {
            alert('Incorrect Serial Code');
        }
                            // Should this really be 20? and not 9?
        else if (d.length == 20 && d5 != code) {
            var serialCode = d.substring(0, 8);
            alert('Serial Code: ' + serialCode);
            $this.val("");
        }                   // What about here?
        else if (d.length == 20 && d5 == code) {
            var flagNumber = d.substring(0, 6);
            var errorNumber = d.substring(7, 10);
            alert('Flag Number ' + flagNumber + '\nError Number ' + 
                   errorNumber);
            $this.val("");
        }
    });        
});
```

### **[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/kkcvL/)**

Comment: Hi Peter, thanks for the help. I didnt get this part "your if statement should probably be if (d.length > 20) otherwise you get an error on every single keypress". Also I cant use onBlur event, reason being, as soon as either of the IF conditions are met, I am going to make an Ajax call. for onblur, I guess I need the input field to be out of focus?

Comment: The blur was just a suggestion. ---- An if statement of `if (d.length != 20)` will produce an alert of `Incorrect Serial Code` for every single keyup event until you enter 20 characters..... 20 alerts, no matter what. So maybe you should only check if the serial number entered has become too long using `if (d.length > 20)` ------- Try it out with `!=20` ==> http://jsfiddle.net/qFVE6/

Comment: @t3ch - And also, you might want to check for a valid serial number before `d.length==20`, since a serial number only has to be 9 long.

Comment: Hi Peter, Thank you very much. Since last few days I was confused for the problem that why its throwing alerts multiple times whenever I am doing d != 20.

Comment: Peter, even after removing jScrollPane code, I am not able to get the focus

Comment: @t3ch - That's odd. When I open this page - http://jsfiddle.net/kkcvL/ - the focus starts on `#serialNumber`. Whenever you want to bring focus to that element use [ **`.focus()`** ](http://api.jquery.com/focus/) like:  `$("#serialNumber").focus();`

Answer (score 1):

The first thing you need to do is get a javascript trace/debugger for your browser.  The one built-in to Chrome is ok, but not great, and FireBug for Firefox is excellent.

Comment: This is the HTML. Nothing fancy in here

Comment: Firebug is for more than HTML.  It will also allow you to set breakpoints, watch variables, etc.  It's definitely worth it to get Firebug and spend some time figuring out how it works.

Comment: @ Cyrena, I just downloaded firebug, trying to figure out how to set breakpoints. Do you see anything wrong in my code ?

Comment: @t3ch - See my answer. Your main problem is that `.jScrollPane()` is undefined. - You have to remember to add in that plugin.